# Deligne tensor product

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, higher-category-theory

I would like to know something about a tensor product of categories and it seems Deligne tensor product is what I am looking for. But the paper "Categories tannakiennes" by Deligne is not available for me. (Even if it is, I am not that familiar with reading in French.)

Is there any good introductory reference for Deligne tensor product in English?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could start with [these notes](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-769-topics-in-lie-theory-tensor-categories-spring-2009/lecture-notes/MIT18_769S09_lec09.pdf) from the [larger set](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-769-topics-in-lie-theory-tensor-categories-spring-2009/lecture-notes/) at [MIT OpenCourseWare](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/).